# Direction from subtracting 2 vectors

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In the game I'm trying to make, the user can move the player by using a virtual joystick, just like in many mobile games. When the finger is put on the screen and then moved in a direction (how far the finger is moved can't make a difference), which makes the player move in that direction.

I'm having trouble with implementing this. The player only goes in the right direction when the finger is dragged almost to the opposite side of the screen. I think the problem is that the it matters where on the screen the touchDown and touchDragged happens. How do I make the touchPositions independent of the position on the screen?

This is my code, the `prevTouchPoint` is to fix that when to finger is no longer moved but still on the screen, the player still moves in the right direction. `position` is the player position.

```
    public void update(float delta) {
        if(moving) {
            Vector2 dif = touchPoint.sub(startPoint);
            touchPoint.set(prevTouchPoint);

            dif.nor();

            position.add(dif);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        startPoint = viewport.unproject(new Vector2(screenX, screenY));
        moving = true;

        Gdx.app.log("Player", "TouchDown");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        moving = false;

        startPoint.set(0, 0);
        touchPoint.set(0, 0);
        prevTouchPoint.set(0, 0);

        Gdx.app.log("Player", "TouchUp");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        if(moving) {
            touchPoint = viewport.unproject(new Vector2(screenX, screenY));
            prevTouchPoint.set(touchPoint);

            Gdx.app.log("Player", "TouchDragged");

            return true;
        }
        else {
            return super.touchDragged(screenX, screenY, pointer);
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way :

```
public class GdxTest extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor{

    ExtendViewport viewport;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Sprite sprite;
    Texture texture;
    Vector2 touchDown,drag,spritePos;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        viewport=new ExtendViewport(400,640);

        touchDown =new Vector2();
        drag =new Vector2();
        spritePos=new Vector2();

        batch=new SpriteBatch();
        sprite=new Sprite(texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
        sprite.setSize(100,100);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){

            Vector2 diff= drag.cpy().sub(touchDown);
            diff.nor();
            touchDown.set(drag);
            spritePos.add(diff.scl(3));
        }

        sprite.setPosition(spritePos.x-sprite.getWidth()/2,spritePos.y-sprite.getHeight()/2);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width,height);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        texture.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        touchDown.set(screenX,screenY);
        viewport.unproject(touchDown);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        touchDown.set(0,0);
        drag.set(0,0);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

        drag.set(screenX,screenY);
        viewport.unproject(drag);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank very much, again :). Could you briefly explain what I did wrong please?

Comment: one thing i notice, by this `touchPoint.set(prevTouchPoint);`  you indirectly setting `prevTouchPoint` to `dif` vector because `dif` is just a reference of touchPoint

Comment: Thank you for the solution and advice!

Comment: For some reason when i try this `if(player.getPosition().x > 0) {
            viewport.getCamera().position.set(new Vector3(player.getPosition().x, 0, 0));
        }` , when the condition is met, when the player is going forward and I want it to go backward, I first have to remove my finger instead of just dragging it to the left, do you happen to know why?